# Why doesn't "foldLeft" work with class members in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to remove classes with identical fields from a collection using `foldLeft` function in Scala.

For example, a `Box` class is defined as: `class Box(color: String = "", size: Int = 0)`

Let's create a simple collection `Seq(Box, Box, Box)` and try to filter it by the `size` field.

```scala
val s = Seq(Box("green", 1), Box("blue", 1), Box("red", 3))

s.foldLeft(Seq(s.head)){ (boxes, nextBox) =>
  if (boxes.last.size != nextBox.size) { // throws an exception
    boxes :+ nextBox
  } else {
    boxes
  }
}
```

The above code throws an exception: `value size cannot be accessed as a member of Box`.
The above code works fine with primitive types and for `Seq(1, 1, 3)` will produce `1, 3`.
It doesn't help if you explicitly tell the compiler `(boxes: Seq[Box], nextBox: Box)`, it doesn't help even if you cast the value returned by `last` to `Box`.

Can you please explain why?

Comment: I think your implementation could be made simpler by using the `distinctBy` function. Something simple like: `s.distinctBy(_.size)`

Comment: `Seq(s.head)` doesn't make sense and is unsafe ... `s.take(1)`

Comment: @cchantep correct, I omitted the part where I check for `nonEmpty`.

Comment: @marstran that is available only from Scala 2.13 unfortunately

Comment: Even with nonEmpty, that's more error prone that `take(1)` that both check and take

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The above code throws an exception: value size cannot be accessed as a member of Box.

Because `Box` doesn't have any public field called `size`; it has a constructor parameter called `size` which is different.
You can fix that doing `class Box(color: String = "", val size: Int = 0)` to make the constructor argument a field; or by using a case class that does that for you *(and much more)*.

PS: It doesn't throw an exception, it fails with a compiler error; two very different things.

---

Also, what you are trying to do is just `distinctBy`; as I always say the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) is your friend.

```scala
final case class Box(color: String = "", size: Int = 0)

val result = boxes.distinctBy(_.size)
```

---

Since you seem very new to the language and with many basic errors / misconceptions I would advise you to pick some course or read a book about the language. Also, I would encourage you to join the **Scala** **Discord** server where you may ask questions and get more interactive help.

Answer (score 1):

Some code must be missing from your description, since you can't call `Box(...)` if `Box` is just a `class`. You could if it were a `case class` and then size would be accessible too, since a case class exposes all it's constructor arguments as members, whereas a standard class does not unless explicitly annotated with `val`:

```
scala> case class Box(color: String = "", size: Int = 0)
class Box

scala> val s = Seq(Box("green", 1), Box("green", 1), Box("green", 3))
val s: Seq[Box] = List(Box(green,1), Box(green,1), Box(green,3))

scala> s.foldLeft(Seq(s.head)){ (boxes, nextBox) =>
     |   if (boxes.last.size != nextBox.size) {
     |     boxes :+ nextBox
     |   } else {
     |     boxes
     |   }
     | }
val res0: Seq[Box] = List(Box(green,1), Box(green,3))
```

Alternatively (notice the new of `val` in the class constructor and `new` to instantiate them):

```
scala> class Box(val color: String = "", val size: Int = 0)
class Box

scala> val s = Seq(new Box("green", 1), new Box("green", 1), new Box("green", 3))
val s: Seq[Box] = List(Box@159424e2, Box@29bcf51d, Box@1e54a6b1)

scala> s.foldLeft(Seq(s.head)){ (boxes, nextBox) =>
     |   if (boxes.last.size != nextBox.size) {
     |     boxes :+ nextBox
     |   } else {
     |     boxes
     |   }
     | }
val res0: Seq[Box] = List(Box@159424e2, Box@1e54a6b1)
```